# Touch Scrolling in HTML5 with Multiple Columns

Tags: javascript, html, css, mobile, iscroll

How can iScroll5 or HTML5 be used to allow touch/momentum scrolling with these attributes:

- A Table with many items, and each item has many columns
- Scrolls vertically and horizontally
- Header is fixed vertically, but header scrolls horizontally with columns

In this scenario, vertical scrolling would affect which list items are displayed, and horizontal scrolling would affect which columns are displayed for the visible list items.

To see an example of this go here and click on "100" to show 100 records:
http://www.tablefixedheader.com/fullpagedemo

This example works correctly *except* for the scrolling does not have a touch/momentum/flick action.

Comment: Could you post a picture or a fiddle without the plugin to show what layout you mean?

Comment: Added example link that works as described except for the momentum scrolling.